# Functions over a $C$ vector space with geometric importance. (How to find the basis?)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, complex-geometry

Searching through our suggested exercises of linear and abstract algebra for solving, I found the following exercise. The reason I am posting this, is that because we haven't went through complex spaces and theory but the exercise is still in the suggested ones, which means I am missing something :

Let $V$ be the $C$-vector space of the complex functions over the set of the vertexes of a square. We define a linear operator $T$ over $V$ to be :

$Tf(x) = f(r(x)) $

where for a vertex $x$, $r(x)$ is the exactly next vertex (going clockwise).

->Describe a basis of $V$, write the matrix of the operator $T$ over the particular base you found, find the eigenvalues and describe the eigenvectors of $T$ as functions over the vertex of the square.

What I searched and tried was :

First of all, going clockwise and since we are speaking for a complex vector space, from what I know I think that $r(x) = -ix$ (correct me if that's wrong).

Also, $f$ is a functional defined as : $f : \mathbb C^m -> \mathbb C$ and $T$ is an operator defined as : $T: V->\mathbb C$. From the definition of the operator and the functional (if I did it correctly), how will I procced to finding the basis? I believe that once I define the basis, I will not have an issue solving the rest of the exercise because it goes as a chain, since you need the basis to find the matrix, then you need the matrix to find the eigenvalues and the eigenvalues for the eigenvectors. Given that I know perfectly the theory for bases, matrices, eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the space $\mathbb R$ of the real numbers, I think that by scrolling through complex-algebra parts of the books I won't have a problem solving it. But I couldn't find such a type of exercise so I can understand how to proceed with the basis in the $\mathbb C$-complex space. I would really appreciate if you could explain how to find the basis, the rest I will finish them, but that's where I am stuck at (the basis).

Comment: A square has four vertices. Your space $V$ contains functions that assign a (complex) number to each of these four vertices. So an element of $V$ is just a tuple of four numbers! Does this sound familiar? Now can you give me a basis for $V$? Don't let the complex part bother you too much. It will not affect anything until the finding of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh, let me give it a hand that way then !

Comment: By the way, what does "tuple" mean ? Because even the greek dictionary word is something that we don't use anymore :P

Comment: An $n$-tuple is a list of $n$ numbers. I.e. $(a_1,\cdots ,a_n)$.

Comment: Oh I get it now. So we have a vector over that space which is $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) $ . Now, the complex number which is assigned, is assigned by the way I thought it did ? $ r(x) = -ix$ ? Then going on like : $Tf(x) = f(-ix) $

Comment: Not quite. You are thinking very geometrically about the square. All we need is that it has four vertices. Label the vertices $1,2,3,4$ clockwise. Then tell me what $f$ should map $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ to?

Comment: Well then it should map $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ to $(1,2,3,4)$ going clockwise of course if I think correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39244/discussion-between-jake-and-charalampos-filippatos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my question after a great help from Jake, through comments and chat :

Let's say that $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ are the four vertices of our square. Then, the operator that assigns them exactly to the next one will give back the vector $(a_2,a_3,a_4,a_1)$. (Note that the fourth one goes back to the first one). Then, a vector $v$ of the space $\mathbb C^4$ that our vertices are assigned, is written as : $v = e_1a_2 + e_2a_3 + e_3a_4 + e_4a_1$.

From that, we get that the basis $B$ is the : $B=\text{span}[(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)]$

And furthermore, the matrix of our operator T :

$ M_T =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix} $

We get that exact matrix, because $(1,0,0,0)$ goes to $(0,0,0,1)$ etc.
After that, we can move on to solving the characteristic polynomial and finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.